# Import from excel to winforms (data not saved) c#

Tags: winforms, excel, export

there are many examples on the web, how to emport data from an excel file to a winform usind Office.Interop.Excel, wheere excel file is stored on the disk. Here is one simple example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:/Users/1/Desktop/test2.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            for (int i = 1; i < rowCount+1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < colCount+1; j++)
                {
                    textBox1.Text= (xlRange.Cells[2,2].Value2.ToString());
                    textBox2.Text = (xlRange.Cells[2, 3].Value2.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunataly I could not find, how to export data, when the excel file is already open, and the data from a thread is loading into the spread sheet, and the numbers in cells are changing every second. In the code above only the last saved data is seen in the textbox. Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem? To be clear, you want to open an Excel workbook and import data from it into your winforms. Then, as the data changes (from the user? other process going on?) you want to record every change every second. Sounds like you need to use a database to record the changes each time that they are made. Or if the data set won't be extremely large, then you could just record it all on another worksheet in Excel.

Comment: No, the excel book is already open. The data is imported into it from another application through DDE. In this application the data changes very quickly, but I need only the latest figure. All previuos figures don't need to be stored. To simlify it- there is one cell in excel sheet with changing data, and a textbox in a winform, which must reflect the latest figure of the excel cell.

Comment: Well, looks like it is not as simple as I thought...

Comment: Look into maybe dynamically adding a named range onto that cell and then hooking into its change event? Interesting problem. When i get home from vacation tomorrow I'll try and look into it

Comment: I have no ideas... lack of experience :(