# Save Excel file in every 2 second without using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save an excel at every 2 seconds. Data is updated in this excel through DDE and want to read this data every 2 seconds. Unfortunately this data is not saved on hard disk.

I am aware of macro which can be used to save file after specified point of time but do not want to use macro.

Since data is updated frequently in this sheet through DDE (at every 100 MS) so sheet change event triggers too often.

Below is the code which i am trying but not getting success.

```
Dim ctme, ptme As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  ctme = Second(Now)
  ptme = ctme - 2

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
ctme = Second(Now)

If (ctme - ptme) = 2 Then
 Me.Save
 ptme = ctme

End If


End Sub
```

Please help

Comment: Updating a spreadsheet every 100ms is via DDE isn't feasible; neither is trying to save a spreadsheet every two seconds. DDE is simply far too slow for this, as is disk IO if there's any volume of data at all. You need to re-think your entire approach, IMO.

Comment: I agree with @KenWhite, every two seconds is maybe a little over ambitious. Operations on a CPU / in memory can easily be done this frequently, but writing to disk takes a little longer. It may be feasible if it is a particuarly small file and / or you are writing to a high speed SSD.

Comment: I am also a little confused about the title 'without using a macro' as you later give code for a macro that you are attempting to use. Do you mean by this that you don't want to use a macro that you record the steps for and use auto code generation, you only want to use macros that you have coded manually using VBA?

Comment: Actually my problem is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008382/import-from-excel-to-winforms-data-not-saved-c-sharp , but as you can see not a single answer to this question, so i am trying for different approach i.e save that file every 2 second and read it.  @chrisPorsser, by macro means i do not want any code written in Subroutine or function. Code must be in event handlers otherwise that DDE do not allow macro to run. Although i only have 1 % hope to get it solved :(

Comment: +1 - to cancel out the -1 as I don't believe this is such a bad question

Comment: You complain below about people using their energy on "postmortems" rather than helping. I'd argue that these are more like "premortems," i.e., trying to help you focus beforehand. In the event that an answer does help, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Does your spreadsheet do anything with the data that is coming in over DDE? And are you trying to read the data with excel or is it just acting as a proxy for your data? If it is, can you not skip excel and go straight to the app that requires the data?

Answer (score 2):

Nidhi, people here are trying to help you and you need to understand that no one has the access to your brain to understand what you actually meant to ask. So it is quite natural to ask questions to understand the issue clearly before suggesting any answer. The people here, get equally frustrated when they are unable to understand a simple question, the time they spend could have been easily saved, had the person spent a little extra time in explaining the things better. So giving credit to those who are trying to help you, will not harm at all.

Ok, coming back to your question. I may be wrong, but I think that SheetChange event is not fired on DDE update. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The next option can be Application.OnTime functionality.

Write the following code in Workbook Open Method:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim currentTime As Date
    currentTime = DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
    Application.OnTime currentTime, "SaveFile"
End Sub
```

Then Add a new Module and add the following Function there in new Module:

```
Public Sub SaveFile()
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    Dim currentTime As Date
    currentTime = DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
    Application.OnTime currentTime, "SaveFile"
End Sub
```

The above code will create a timer which would run every two seconds to save your file. There are pros and cons for this approach, but it's Excel's best possible Timer functionality. Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks,
Vikas

Comment: Hi Vikas , i too coded in same way earlier. But problem is when we write some other function or Sub routine then that application (which is updating excel via DDE do not allow this file to open) . Otherwise it was too simple question to ask here. Main issue is only that what ever we have to code , it must be in event handlers(strictly). I am stuck is this problem from last 10 days :(

Comment: As far as I know Workbook Open is also an even and all we need to do is to start a timer on WorkBook Open Event. Are you saying that the application you use to trigger the DDE triggers the SheetChange event and not other events like WorkbookOpen?  Ok, I am getting it a little. So if we talk about your DDE application, do you bind an Excel file with your DDE application and it keeps on updating your file? Can you please tell me if this DDE is a standard DDE available on internet to download, or is it made by you or your colleagues in house?

Answer (score 1):

(this is totally away from the OP tags but just thought I'd put forward a possible alternative)

Create a small `.NET` console application.

User one of the `Timer` objects available to create this timed loop you require.

Then using a reference to Excel Interop library on each sweep of the loop it looks like you might need to open this workbook, save it, and then close it again .....depending on the calculations within the book and the size of the `Excel` file is it physically possible on your machine to open/calculate/save within 2 seconds?

Comment: thanks a lot atleast you gave a try. What is most disappointing here is people consumes their energy in doing postmortem of question rather trying to reply and help. Thanks once again. Can you please tell me is it possible to do open , save and close excel file when it is already opened on computer by some other application and DDE updation is going on

Comment: - would it be ok if the computer that already has it open has it open _read-only_ ?